# Stubbing S3 uploads in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, mocha.js, sinon

How would I go about stubbing S3 uploads in Node.js?

For insight, I'm using Mocha for tests and Sinon for stubbing, but I'm open to changing anything. I have a file that exports a function that performs the upload. It looks like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET }});
var params = { Key: key, Body: body };
s3.upload(params, function (error, data) {
  // Handle upload or error
});
```

If I try to stub `AWS.S3` or `AWS.S3.prototype`, nothing changes. I assume this is because my tests have required `aws-sdk` themselves and have their own copy of each function.

My test looks like this:

```
describe('POST /files', function () {
  var url = baseURL + '/files';
  it('uploads the file to s3', function (done) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var formData = {
      video: fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + '/test/support/video.mp4')
    };
    var params = {url: url, formData: formData};
    request.post(params, function (error, response, body) {
      expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(200);
      expect(response.body).to.eq('Uploaded');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This test works fine, but it does not stub the upload to S3, so the upload actually goes through :X.

Comment: If it's helpful, rather than stubbing you could replace the host that the AWS SDK uses so that it uses a dummy host.  There are also servers for emulating S3 that you can run locally.

Comment: @Brad That's definitely an option if stubbing doesn't work out. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can stub with [Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) as follows if you'd like:

1. Expose the `AWS.S3` instance:

   ```
   var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
   var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET }});
   var params = { Key: key, Body: body };
   exports.s3.upload(params, function (error, data) {

   });
   //Expose S3 instance
   exports.s3 = s3;
   ```
2. Stub the same instance like so:

   ```
   var sinon = require('sinon');
   //Import module you are going to test
   var UploadService = require('./uploadService');

   describe('POST /files', function () {

     before(function() {
       //Stub before, and specify what data you'd like in the callback.
       this.uploadS3Stub = sinon.stub(uploadService.s3, 'upload').callsArgWith(1, null, { data: 'Desired response' });
     });

     after(function() {
       //Restore after
       this.uploadS3Stub.restore();
     });

     var url = baseURL + '/files';
     it('uploads the file to s3', function (done) {
       var fs = require('fs');
       var formData = {
         video: fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + '/test/support/video.mp4')
       };
       var params = {url: url, formData: formData};
       var self = this;

       request.post(params, function (error, response, body) {
         expect(response.statusCode).to.eq(200);
         expect(response.body).to.eq('Uploaded');
         //You can also check whether the stub was called :)
         expect(self.uploadS3Stub.calledOnce).to.eql(true);
         done();
       });
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Old answer but worth noting it works as promised.
Just one note - its sinon.stub not Sinon.stub

Comment: Hey @LiviuR, updated answer so that it is `sinon.stub`. Also maybe take a look at the answer suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243647/sinon-stub-in-node-with-aws-sdk/28736661#28736661, as it seems to be more popular than using sinon directly

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to mock S3 in Node.

Some modules specific to S3:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-s3
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-aws-s3

Some modules for general AWS mocking:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-aws-sinon
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-aws

And you can even start a simple server that responds to some of the S3 API calls:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3rver

The last one can easily be used in other languages and runtimes, not only in Node.

Answer (score 1):

```
s3UploadStub = AWS.S3.prototype.upload = sandbox.stub();



 it("should  upload  successfully", async function() {
        s3UploadStub.yields(null, data);
        let response = await FileUtil.uploadFile(fileReference,data);
        expect(s3UploadStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
        expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(response.body).to.equal(fileReference);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create stubs using sinon and replace the variables in the code you're testing with the stubs. There are a few modules to do this, try [Mockery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery) or [Rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire). For example with Rewire you load the module you're testing using `rewire` instead of `require` then use `__set__` to set the variables.

```
var rewire = require('rewire');
var moduleUnderTest = rewire('myModule');
moduleUnderTest.__set__('s3', stubbedS3);
```