# How to stub AWS.SQS.sendMessage with Sinon?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sinon

I have Node.js code that writes a message to an SWS queue.
I'm trying to stub this code in my unit tests.

Source:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});
sqs.sendMessage(myMessage, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
  });
```

In My unit tests I'm trying to do something like this to stub the call:

```
sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
sandbox.stub(AWS.SQS,'sendMessage').callsFake((message,fn) => {
  console.log("Stub AWS sendMessage");
});
sandbox.restore();
```

I am getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property sendMessage

Comment: Check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243647/sinon-stub-in-node-with-aws-sdk), it includes a link to an npm module that mocks out all the AWS SDK services, and examples for stubbing them

Answer (score 1):

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("dummy describe", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    // use this if you want to stub SQS for all the iteration
    sinon.stub(AWS, "SQS").returns({
      sendMessage() {
        return {
          promise() {
            return Promise.resolve();
          }
        };
      }
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore(); // use this to restore the stubbed function
  });

  it("dummy test success", async () => {
    sinon.stub(AWS, "SES").returns({ // this is what you need
      sendRawEmail() {
        return {
          promise() {
            return Promise.resolve();
          }
        };
      }
    });
  });
});
```

For more check [this](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243647/sinon-stub-in-node-with-aws-sdk).

You can use the [aws-sdk-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk-mock) package.

> It's really easy to use. Just call AWS.mock with the service, method
>   and a stub function.

```
AWS.mock('SQS', 'sendMessage', function(params, callback) {
    callback(null, 'success'); 
});
```